# Importing Data from excel into sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to import data into sql server using ssis packages. I have a column named description and that has a cell having 690 characters.

I am getting a truncation error as SSIS is not able to figure out the maximum length required. I tried changing the output column properties from the excel source connection but that didn't help. However, when I move the cell with the maximum length to the first row it works perfectly (as ssis package determines the max length from the first 8 rows).

Since, I want to automate this process I don't want to modify the excel sheet each and every time. I have read about changing the number of rowsets that ssis reads, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a Data Conversion step in your Data Flow. You should be able to specify the output column as string in the size you need (don't forget to update the mapping to use the new column).

Comment: Is data conversion necessary? It is coming in a text/string format. It needs ntext data type  but its considering nvarchar and even if I increase the number of characters for the nvarchar it is not helping.

Comment: @JacobH Hey so when I use data conversion. It says a new error saying failed to retrieve long data for the column description.

Comment: Try DT_WSTR instead? (unicode string instead of ntext)

Comment: @JacobH Tried, with 700, 800 and 1000 (longest length is 690). Doesn't work.

Comment: @JacobH Data conversion won't work as the excel source connection cant read the long ass data in the column of description which is the issue point.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/ar-sa/help/281517/prb-transfer-of-data-from-jet-4.0ledb-source-fails-with-buffer-overflow-error

Comment: @Hadi I had to eventually do that. However, I was hoping I could get another workaround for that here. The problem with that is the projects that are already there also get affected which might cause an issue (mostly unlikely).

Comment: What is your Excel Connection String - it should contain IMEX =1 like this: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=FileName;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\";. See https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: Did that as well. Doing IMEX=1 allows the connection manager to change the data type according to the column data. However, it again boils down to that, it predicts that by looking at the top 8 rows. Moreover, I don't have an issue of datatype, rather its the field length. 

The answer I have given worked for me. But, I am trying to find something else in which I wouldn't have to mess with the registry (not that it is a big issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is that you go to windows registry and change the excel connection manager to see more than 8 rows to determine the column data type and length, which solves the issue.

You go to windows registry by typing "regedit" in the run console and when you are in the windows registry you follow

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Wow6432Node -> Microsoft -> Jet -> 4.0 ->Engines -> Excel -> and then set the typeguessrows to 0, so that it can parse through the entire file instead of the top 8 rows.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the length of your Excel Source input columns.

In your SSIS Package, right click on the Excel source in the data flow task and click on "Advance Editor for Excel Source".  Next change the data type and length of the column from its default value.

If you are using VS2015 or above, right-clic on the Excel Source and clic properties. In the bottom part of the properties clic in the `Show Advance Editor` link and change the length in the `Input and Output Properties` tab.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: It does not work. I changed the data type and length of the output columns. But the external columns don't change. I cant change those values either. 

Is this what you were recommending?

Comment: The problem is the excel source thinks the column has a maximum length of 255 which it gets through the top 8 rows. Do you know any workaround for that without going to windows registry.

Comment: You need to change both values, the output colum length and the external column length. Try it.

Comment: Cant change the external column length. When I change it, and then refresh it goes back to what it originally was.